# ubuntu on a usb wont load computer says remove media device

Tags: boot, live-usb, iso

OK so i have the iso its to big for the cd roms i own and i put on usb changed boot up to the usb.
but it says remove media device and pres enter when i do that it starts windows normal i have reformatted the usb and still the same.

i have re downloaded the iso tried both for the 2 gig ram and its just keep on saying remove media device and press enter.

only thing i have left to do is put both iso on the thumb drive and try that.

Answer (score 0):

Make usb(pen drive) bootable using poweriso tool or other tools available. Without making usb bootable its not possible to install.
[see here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)